# can't install mariadb because of Cannot link cmake

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

I'm sorry if my question is a little newbie, i just get Mac in my job and I'm usually a Linux user...
I'm trying to install mariadb to use it after with python, i tried with brew. I know it's old version of macOS (and i can't do anything about it)

```
brew install mariadb
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from MacHomebrew on Twitter.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.

==> Fetching dependencies for mariadb: cmake, fmt, mecab, mecab-ipadic, msgpack, ca-certificates, openssl@1.1, pcre, groonga, pcre2, xz and zstd
==> Fetching cmake
==> Downloading https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.25.2/cmake-3.25.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b19b531ca705f5d1736fb10a83767e06ac2e8801a3f9f34ac8b4bd6e1697dda2--cmake-3.25.2.tar.gz
==> Fetching fmt
==> Downloading https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/archive/9.1.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d39fe7ae376a7198a34490e5acb665b0112ea585720eb917c496bb050bc76c62--fmt-9.1.0.tar.gz
==> Fetching mecab
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mecab/manifests/0.996-3
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/21431e68751945bd7900be15e222a38b4402841088e6d5669b4f48c56dc614b3--mecab-0.996-3.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mecab/blobs/sha256:ef261d203140305ca8c9e4b7311c61176a17325df9454610d3eb33a312c4d3c5
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/45441007488c38750c14c63895eccd562a5af40519f48eed3e35ce6eb10fbb13--mecab--0.996.mojave.bottle.3.tar.gz
==> Fetching mecab-ipadic
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mecab-ipadic/manifests/2.7.0-20070801
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/011316e018929eb52aa0a17e2d6634fe3804c07bf44859f3cc7a0b4baf0e3cea--mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mecab-ipadic/blobs/sha256:30967b4167d34f05c79f185d71a40198fff4067d0cce82aed59383548c898681
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f5097a021ff29918177e2d4279101124910e2f287932a3619641988e92f66a76--mecab-ipadic--2.7.0-20070801.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Fetching msgpack
==> Downloading https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/releases/download/c-5.0.0/msgpack-c-5.0.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c58619083eaba272e9c477c3c0deb886dc539140f009dd42dc2634e8db0378a3--msgpack-c-5.0.0.tar.gz
==> Fetching ca-certificates
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/manifests/2023-01-10
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/927414ed081d996b84d938be6af4d2639403b4d2bee3cc29268d0844999da180--ca-certificates-2023-01-10.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/blobs/sha256:11fe9d0a98a2ac454fa1db95762a697c3340f46560ff27e5e9db8fdeb003f17e
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ca2448928ab98c455b5e46d4a6604247a151ab0f4e60553dbb5c6aecd2e1df3c--ca-certificates--2023-01-10.all.bottle.tar.gz
==> Fetching openssl@1.1
==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ec3feb171aa63b32c30a6e7423e78f743f92d1ef984b66b0ea548d08220c0ce6--openssl-1.1.1t.tar.gz
==> Fetching pcre
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pcre/manifests/8.45
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4a3bba0e8d1899c13ac3442d2c49df6c1999948bdc0943f2f179693257d82545--pcre-8.45.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pcre/blobs/sha256:a42b79956773d18c4ac337868cfc15fadadf5e779d65c12ffd6f8fd379b5514c
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/456b31dd91116840800d9cc2f35c6f2ebde8cfe8513e6d08dd6974f3309dc4f9--pcre--8.45.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Fetching groonga
==> Downloading https://packages.groonga.org/source/groonga-normalizer-mysql/groonga-normalizer-mysql-1.2.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8bc84be3a691a3cf950cf2576dac8b64884fd7f4f91026475399827c9d96fd6b--groonga-normalizer-mysql-1.2.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://packages.groonga.org/source/groonga/groonga-13.0.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/31a0c28bde3252bed7d10bba33dec5ef45e6a5379da383e40c28f668bb03878d--groonga-13.0.0.tar.gz
==> Fetching pcre2
==> Downloading https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/releases/download/pcre2-10.42/pcre2-10.42.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7f4d74ac3e447b9fed53bce4202af3921ffc5ae1469894e7e1b10bda2145a15b--pcre2-10.42.tar.bz2
==> Fetching xz
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lzmautils/xz-5.4.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ca0c062e8ecb14160415874ad277c80d73d9a9d00aa926ff11a32e877f6651fe--xz-5.4.1.tar.gz
==> Fetching zstd
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/zstd/archive/v1.5.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a7632ef95a5b612da27d37abb163299230d9f9394c53a8385de8c57a366c2ebe--zstd-1.5.4.tar.gz
==> Fetching mariadb
==> Downloading https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.10.3/source/mariadb-10.10.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/182c68feeae25618d12662bea09676695697b3545a81c63d59850e574372c312--mariadb-10.10.3.tar.gz
==> Installing dependencies for mariadb: cmake, fmt, mecab, mecab-ipadic, msgpack, ca-certificates, openssl@1.1, pcre, groonga, pcre2, xz and zstd
Error: Cannot link cmake
Another version is already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.24.2
```

i tried to upgrade cmake in case of but i wasn't a better try:

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
cmake 3.24.2 -> 3.25.2
==> Fetching cmake
==> Downloading https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.25.2/cmake-3.25.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/cea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b19b531ca705f5d1736fb10a83767e06ac2e8801a3f9f34ac8b4bd6e1697dda2--cmake-3.25.2.tar.gz
==> Upgrading cmake
  3.24.2 -> 3.25.2 

Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake
```

if someone has any solutions for me thanks!